# Update a table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql, update-attributes

I have a table `A(:name, :address, :phone)` and want to update the names and addresses of all the records. The following lines of code helps me doing it but takes a lot of time :

```
A.find_each(batch_size: 10000) do |a|
  new_name = "xyz"
  new_address = "abc"
  A.find(a.id).update(name: name, address: new_address)
end
```

It takes times because of the last line as I am finding the record first, then updating it. Now when I do this :

```
A.find_each(batch_size: 10000) do |a|
  a.name = "xyz"
  a.address = "abc"
  a.save
end
```

The names and addresses don't get updated in this case but a.save returns true. What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Can you try printing out the errors while saving if any:

```
A.find_each(batch_size: 10000) do |a|
 a.name = "xyz"
 a.address = "abc"
 a.save
 puts a.errors.full_messages
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to do this like:

```
A.find_each(batch_size: 10000){ |a| a.update_attributes(name: 'name', address: 'address', phone: 23213) }
```

Comment: After doing this too, the object 'a' doesn't get updated

Comment: Do I need to have "name" and "address" in attr_accessible ?

Comment: If your model has some `attr_accessible` params already specified, then you should include "name" and "address" to them.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all records to be updated with same value, the below solution will be fast.

```
A.update_all(name: 'xyz', address: 'abc')
```

Comment: No, they are not the same value

Answer (score 0):

You can fire direct `SQL` query and update directly using single SQL statement

```
A.find_by_sql "UPDATE table SET name = 'abc' and address = 'xyz'";
```

Comment: I need to update different rows with different values

Answer (score 0):

```
A.update_all(name: 'xyz', address: 'abc')
```